# what's reason of platform unsupported when I try to use "cnpm install"?

Tags: node.js

In this case, cnpm is chinese edison of "npm",it's just the mirror image of npm. This is my package.json file.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.2",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^1.7.0"
  }
```

when I try "cnpm install", the console says:

```
platform unsupported babel-loader@6.4.1 › webpack@2.5.1 › watchpack@1.3.1 › chokidar@1.7.0 › fsevents@^1.0.0 Package require os(darwin) no   t compatible with your platform(win32)
```

I can gurantee this is not the reason of "cnpm",but I don't know why this happens.